# Find string in text but I also want text before and after the occurance

Tags: c#

Heres what I'm looking for:

I have a "keyword" value... lets say "fox".  I have a "message" value like "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".  Ideally my return would be +X or -X characters on either side of the occurrence like:  "...quick brown fox jumps over..."  (I'll add the ellipsis after).

What is a good, performant approach to this problem?  I'm concerned that keywords could occur at the beginning of the message and also don't want it churning a lot on each of these message evaluations.  I also don't mind if words are cut off.

Couple of things that come to mind when working with this is that I could use some sort of string.contains combined with string.substring.. etc.  Is that far off?

Comment: Your suggestion sounds like you have the right approach: you have to find the starting index of your string, and the end index of your string, and add/subtract an offset from those, and then get that substring of the original. `string.IndexOf` would be the method you need to find the starting point of your search string. Short of actually writing the code for you, I'm not sure what else you'd need!

Comment: Is this for something internal (such as exception messages or the DebuggerDisplay attribute) or for UI text? In the latter case, things are a bit more complicated: (1) A grapheme can consist of more than one char, (2) glyphs have varying widths (in proportional fonts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex

```
 ".{0,"+X+"}"+Regex.Escape(keyword)+".{0,"+X+"}"
```

So,if keyword is `fox` and X is 5,your regex would be

```
 .{0,5}fox.{0,5}
```

This regex would match 0 to 5 characters at the `right` and `left` side of `fox`.

---

Your code

```
 String output=Regex.Match(input,regex).Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.IndexOf` method to find the location of the find, then calculate some offsets based on the return value and the length of the string, and then you can retrieve the keyword +/- X characters with `Substring` method.

Comment: Yup - just make sure you don't exceed the limits of string indexing when using the `Substring`.